# Facebook open graph timeline application - How to connect/use other objects in your own timeline application

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have created an facebook app added an object and an action to this app. And publishing to my facebook site works fine in the timeline. But, if I want my app to connect to build in object in the open graph I cannot choose theese object within my application, for exsample:
In my app I choose my action type and then in the field "connected types". The values I can choose here is the object I created within the app namespace and only "profile", "website", "book" in the open graph namespace and "games" in namespace Games. But what about all the other build in objects in the open graph, for example Video, music and audio. How do I connect to theese objects from my app.

I am really stuck here, so I hope the community can help me.

Anita

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently supported to read objects and actions from other applications, I'm not aware of a plan to release APIs for that, but they'd be announced on the [Developer Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog) or [Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap) if they were released