# Can customer open graph objects be used in multiple sites?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm not sure the best way to ask this, but is it possible to reuse a custom object type defined in one app so that it aggregates on the timeline with objects of the same type from another app?

I see news articles doing this in my own timeline, such as Guardian and Yahoo news articles appearing in the same aggregate box. I'd like to do this with my main blog as well as another blog project, both of which are about puzzles. Since I have the object type defined as thegriddle:puzzle in my app, can I use that object type with a second app in order to make the items aggregate together? (i.e. "Solved Puzzles" listing puzzles solved on The Griddle and on the second blog)

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same concern and have found no way around the limitation of 1 app -> 1 domain.

You may have some luck if you associate the Website URL to one domain and the Mobile URL to another.  But to be honest that is silly and probably doesn't even deserve being mentioned.

So as far as I can tell, the answer is no, not at this time.  Although I hope this issue is resolved soon.  Maintaining 4-5 apps / submitting action object approval for each is a timesink.

As far as two items from different apps showing up in the same stream - that could be because they are grouped by opengraph actions or objects.

References:

- [Facebook open graph timeline application - How to connect/use other objects in your own timeline application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047754/facebook-open-graph-timeline-application-how-to-connect-use-other-objects-in-y)
- Personal experience.